# Want to remove / ( -) . from phone number strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want to remove symbols in phone numbers. Sometimes it is in the format of 151-454-6545 but sometimes it is in (545)-(564)-(5465) and in sometimes it is in 548.445.8454. I am using

```
val.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) -$2-$3')
```

for replacing.. but it doesn't remove the dot.What to do  remove the dot also? expected output like 545-455-4545

Comment: first, remove all symbols, then format according to desired structure

Comment: your regex is looking for 1234567890 ... i.e. 10 digits with nothing between them, therefore doesn't match, therefore doesn't replace - your input is 11 digits ... so that's another issue

Comment: `val.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) -$2-$3')` ?

Comment: also `expected output like 545-455-4545` ... yet the replace value you try is `($1) -$2-$3` ... so, do you want the `()` or not?

Comment: this? https://regex101.com/r/Wavw45/1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a non-digit expression to replace them by '-' string :

```
  val.replace(/^\D+/, '')
  .replace(/\D+$/, '')
  .replace(/\D+/g, '-')
```

Let me know if it does what you need.

EDIT : trim whitespaces

Comment: but the OP want `545-455-4545` output ... or `(123) -456-7890` - it's really unclear what OP wants to be honest, but :p with input `(545)-(564)-(5465)` your regex would output `-454-564-5465-`

Comment: Yes it's not very clear but I updated to trim whitespaces at least

Answer (score 0):

here is a version with only 1 regex

https://regex101.com/r/Wavw45/1

regex

`[^\d\n]*(\d{3})[^\d\n]+(\d{3,4})[^\d\n]+(\d{4})[^\d\n]*`

replace (or whatever pattern you want)

`($1) -$2-$3`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.replace(/^\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*$/, '$1-$2-$3')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KVKCyA/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```